# OpenERP 7.0 Kanban View - Unable to show group column without data

Tags: odoo, kanban

I've created a kanban view in a module,
I set the `default_group_by` property in kanban with the `state` field.
The state contains:

```
[('new','Waiting Queue'),('in_progress','In Progress'),('done','Finished')]
```

but where's there's no data in specific state,the column for the state will not appear until I create a data with that state.
is there any way to workaround this problem guy ?thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a _group_by_full method. This method must return the (name_get of records, {id: fold}) to include in the _read_group, if grouped on this field. Of course, you can return all values of column you want, even if there is not yet data for this column.
You can see clear examples of _group_by_full in project.py and crm_lead.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with _group_by_full dictionnary, to add in your osv.osv class.

For example check my sample code:

```
def _read_group_state_ids(self, cr, uid, ids, domain, read_group_order=None, access_rights_uid=None, context=None):

    stage_obj = self.pool.get('produce.book.stage')
    order = stage_obj._order

    if read_group_order == 'stage_id desc':
        order = "%s desc" % order
    # perform search
    stage_ids = stage_obj._search(cr, uid, [], order=order, access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid, context=context)
    result = stage_obj.name_get(cr, access_rights_uid, stage_ids, context=context)
    # restore order of the search
    result.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(stage_ids.index(x[0]), stage_ids.index(y[0])))

    fold = {}
    for stage in stage_obj.browse(cr, access_rights_uid, stage_ids, context=context):
        fold[stage.id] = stage.fold or False
    return result, fold

_group_by_full = {
    'stage_id': _read_group_state_ids
}
```

result is a list of tuples contains (id, name) and fold is a dictionary of pair {id: bool} that if each one be true that column will be fold.